# Service URL for Oracle Cloud Storage (S3 API) using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-pipelines, oracle-adf, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to connect to Oracle Cloud Storage (S3 API) using given credentials.
Please help me to form the link to connect to the Files in the storage.
**https://.compact.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com**
Looking for your help who are expert in this.

Regards
Shanu

Comment: Detailed explanation already available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm). Did you even try it or need help from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/s3objectstorage/20160918/) is the endpoint format:
https://<object_storage_namespace>.compat.objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com

1. You are missing the first part: object storage namespace;
2. your second part is "compact" and the correct is "compat;

There are [three ways](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/understandingnamespaces.htm) to get the namespace (OCI Console, CLI, API). I use the command in the Cloud Shell:

`oci os ns get`

To access Cloud Shell, in the Menu Bar is the icon between Region and Code Editor.
[image]